# Where to add files in NetBeans (8.1)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar, embedded-resource

I've created a Java Swing application and it all seems to work fine until I try and distribute it. I'm making use of a HMTL file (which is located at the project root), however when generating the final .jar for the project, this file (along with the images documents in various `<src>` tags) cannot be found, as the current working directory has changed from the root, to root/dist.

Is there a correct way to include files (such as .html) into the project, so they can included with the .jar?

Comment: See the examples cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info), in the [tag:embedded-resource] tag.

Comment: *"a HMTL file (which is located at the project root)"* First you should verify that the HTML file was included in the Jar. Then follow the advice offered by @trashgod for getting an URL and loading it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are such ways.

**For embedded files:**

You would put them inside your NetBeans project packages and get their location through this.getClass().getResource(String path).getPath()
Which is a string that can be passed as a parameter to create a File object.
(When specifying the path you must begin with a / which means from root.
E.g package animal.dog has husky.txt, you would use the path /animal/dog/husky.txt)

**For external files:**

You would use something like your_class.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
To get the location in which the .jar is running.

Comment: *"..getResource(String path) And use that to get the file path,which can be used in a File object."* It's not a `File` path and cannot be used as a `File`! `getResource(..)` returns a `URL` (which can be read as an `URL`, but not written to like a `File`). The 2nd idea won't work for any desktop app. launched using Java Web Start.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help from everyone. The solution to my problem was actually different, so I'll post it here to complete this post. It actually turned out that I was using the wrong class loader, for me the correct class loader was attained via:

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

Once I used that loader, everything *magically* worked.